# New version upload on TestFlight after prior version is already on App store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I have developed app and so many times I have uploaded on iTunes connect (TestFlight). Like :

Version      Build

1.5    —>   1.0   This build is live — on App Store

1.4    —>   1.9

1.4    —>   1.8

1.4    —>   1.7

1.4    —>   1.6

……….

1.3    —>   1.9

1.3    —>   1.8

……..

and so on…..

Now I need to update one change and want to give for testing to my other friends, So I am trying to upload new version `1.5  —>  1.1’ on iTunes connect (TestFlight) through Xcode, but it gives error like : Version must be higher than the existing version on iTunes connect.

Before making live, I have uploaded so many build for the same version and same via Xcode , at that time it is done successfully uploaded. 
Then why it gives me error now ? 
What it means to say ? 
How can I upload on TestFlight for testing ?

Please suggested me, what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to your app has become Live (Ready For Sale) on the AppStore.

I think Apple consider the version life cycle completed once the version is available to public users via AppStore.

In your case, 1.5 (1) is Live on AppStore which means version 1.5 life cycle completes with final version being 1.5 (1).
So, you would not be able to add any further new build with 1.5 version. Instead, you should create a new version higher than 1.5, i.e., 1.5.1, 1.6, and then upload the builds to that newly created version.

This is just my assumption, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

For me.. i regularly updating build(not version) and uploading the it to testflight and works, even i have uploaded it today just 1 hour ago and it worked fine. I think, you should clean->build and do same process again. Sometimes after changing build number, you might not have build the target and directly archived, in that case, such a errors are thrown by Apple.

So the probable solution is to just

clean->build -> archieve .... do same process again and upload it to appstore.

Comment: I have tried all these things. And note that my all build is also working fine. Just I want to upload new `build 1.1` for `version 1.5` for TestFlight only but not want to make it live. Because my earlier build is already live on store.

Comment: yes i understand that.. just want to release it on testflight, not making live on store. But, still it should work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue. I released 1.0 build 5 to App Store(live). Had to make some quick changes, so tried to change the build number and released to Test Flight through iTunes Connect. I got no warnings or any errors. However, when I login to iTunesConnect and check in Activity tab the build number for that specific version says "The build is invalid" with a red exclamation.

Solution: Just increase the version no, not the build no if the app is already live.