# Does testflight reviews app again if i up the version number?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store, testflight

I have few queries about test flight build uploads . As i know the basic steps but i have questions still as this will be first time i shall be uploading build to Testflight

**A)** **My App is already there in App Store with version 1.0 , so if i want to upload a new version 2.0 of the same app in Test Flight will it be reviewed again? If yes what is the maximum waiting time?**

**B) As my app is already live in Appstore with Version 1.0 and Build no: 28 can i upload the same version with build number as 29 to testflight for beta testing?**

**C) Also i read for internal testers TestFlight doesnot have review time , what does it means in clear sense?**

**D) Also once the new version is uploaded to the testflight the invitation for testing it must be sent seperately? Because when i used to upload by just changing the Build Number testers used to get notified about it in TestFlight but after uploading with new version 2.0 i have doubts regarding this.**

Any clarification or answers to these questions would help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into these documents

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devdc42b26b8
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/distributing-your-app-for-beta-testing-and-releases

Answer (score 2):

**The Testflight Review Process**

**1)**
For TestFlight, when you submit a new version number, it requires a new review(Ranging from 48 hrs to 3 days in worst cases).

**2)**
But new build numbers do not require a new review(build numbers are like a secondary ID for a version as it goes through development).

> For instance, I could push a new version of Apollo to TestFlight,
> version 1.8 (build number 50) and it would need review, but builds 51,
> 52, 53, etc. of the same version do not require any review.
>
> Similarly if you have 1.7 version of your app and you want to upload a
> new version 1.8 it will require a new review (Ranging from 48 hrs to 3
> days in worst cases)

**3)** Also while uploading the build to Test flight sometimes the internal testers may not get notification to test though they were invited earlier and also it shows "missing compliance" in TestFlight build in that case simply add this key in plist file...Everything will be alright..

```
<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>  
<false/>
```

**4)**

Suppose if your app has become Live (Ready For Sale) on the AppStore with version 1.5 and build number 1.9.

I think Apple consider the version life cycle completed once the version is available to public users via AppStore.

> For example, 1.5 (1.9) is Live on AppStore which means version 1.5
> life cycle completes with final version being 1.5 (1.9 build version).
> So, you would not be able to add any further new build with 1.5
> version. Instead, you should create a new version higher than 1.5,
> i.e., 1.5.1, 1.6, and then upload the builds to that newly created
> version.

If you try with same version number and different build number and is live in App Store you will get error as shown below:

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52719866/14621362
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45207369/14621362

A good article worth reading: https://christianselig.com/2020/06/testflight-review/